# Convert webm (or any other) format's chunks to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

Is it possible to get webm ( or other format ) chucks from a http post (upload) on my sever (i know how to do this).... then feed them as chucks (chunks recieved from browser) to gstreamer or ffmpeg to be converted to mp4 with reduced quality without loading the entire file in memory or to disk  before saving the converted mp4? Why I dont want them to be loaded fully into memory or disk? scalability

Comment: You probably mean "http get".

Comment: No, thanks for your comment, it made me realize I needed to update the question making it clear it is a server receiving the chunks from a browser

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can feed ffmpeg one frame at a time without keeping the whole video file locally. You can read chunks of data from http stream and give them to ffmpeg library to decode. Here is an official [example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html#l00324).

Comment: I updated the question making it clear it is a server receiving the chunks from a browser, does your answer still apply?

Comment: Yes, my answer still applies. You can transcode many sstreaming formats "on the fly". A common HTTP-based video streaming technique, [HLS](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-HLS-(HTTP-Live-Streaming)-78221.aspx) involves multi-frame chunks of encoded data, which may require intermediate storage. But these chunks are relatively small, and cause no problems unless you are concerned about latency of retranslation.